# jQuery: selecting only specific elements with .children()

Tags: jquery, html

I know I can select all child elements of one object by using $(element).children() , but how do I, for example, only select the children of that element that are divs?

Example:

I want to hide every div element from here except the first one that is an a element. How do I do that? `$(".info").children().hide()` just hides everything, and I want the shrink class element to be untouched.

```
<div class="info">
    <a class="shrink" href="#">X</a>

    <div id="info1">
        <p>aaa</p>
    </div>

   <div id="info2">
       <p>bbb</p>
   </div>

   <div id="info3">
       <p>ccc</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the DOC: http://api.jquery.com/children/ ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `children()` method accepts a selector, so you can simply use:

```
$(".info").children('div').hide()
```

Or you can negate the need for `children()` entirely:

```
$('.info div').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
$(".info div").hide();
```